# Find a word within Text in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

Before posting I've searched a lot but I've not found what exactly I was searching for. The question is quite simple.

I've a text in a table (database **MySql**) which has to use **InnoDB engine** (so I can't use [FULL-TEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) which requires MyIsam as engine). My goal is to **find a word in the text**. The word, as you can easily guess, can be surrounded by space, tabs, marks and so on and can be at the start, in the middle or at the end of this text.

I know that I can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator and infact I use it but the SQL statement that I made it's not exactly what I need and so I thought to post the question. This is my actual SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field REGEXP '[[:space:][:graph:]]+THEWORD[[:space:][:graph:]]+'
```

How I can achieve my goal?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundary markers:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]THEWORD[[:>:]]'
```

(found in the [MySQL 5.1 Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are actually trying to create a mechanism for searching the word within some text content. If you need to do this multiple times (eg. with every request search on your site), I suggest you should **index the words in another tables** (eg. one table for the words, where all of them are unique, and one connector table between contents and words).

This will significantly speed up queries designed to get the content with specific words in it. Keep in mind however, that this is a long term solution and is a better idea when you want to make such searches many times and each search will influence the speed of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest I'll keep this in mind. Anyway, firstly I would find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to index the words outside of the database, in an indexed search engine like Lucene.  I know this doesn't address your question directly, but if you have a large database, and/or it is used in a high-concurrency context, trying to search for individual words becomes a big problem and performance suffers.  You can try to index the words into another database table, but there are some serious limitations with this.  For example, what if you want a search for "run" to match "ran" or "running"?  What if you want a search for "meta-data" to match "meta data" and "medadata"?  Indexed search engines have features like stemming and synonyms that can great power and flexibility to your search abilities.  Not to mention that they are optimized and cached for search, as opposed to query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I know Lucene but for the moment I need to use REGEXP or something like this. In this case I need to find the match exactly so the additional Lucene functions are in excess.